# What is the most reliable clearfix method for HTML in emails?

Tags: html, css, email, clearfix

`clear` doesn't work in Outlook 2007/2010, as well as `display` (and many other CSS properties). What should I use?

I need to support all of the clients in [this matrix](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/), except Lotus Notes.

FYI: I am using an XSL that is building **all grid-based markup with tables**. However, I have a table unit that is overlapping another (only in Outlook 2007/2010) somehow.

Comment: We too use campaign monitor, i've just redone our most popular template following the best practices set out in the link in my answer, and it's 100% better than before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As much as it pains me to say it, you must use tables for email templates. This tutorial on Nettuts will help you out [20 Email Design Best Practices and Resources for Beginners](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/20-email-design-best-practices-and-resources-for-beginners)

Comment: Email clients stink for rendering so you got to do what you got to do.  Tables it is.  +1 for a good link. :)

Comment: @David: Try 100% width on those tables (mentioned in the article)

Comment: Thanks for the link. It suggests stacking, instead of nesting, tables. This might solve my clearing woes! Although I need to update my "box" template, I've found quick and dirty `<br/>`s to suffice in the mean time.

Comment: I followed the guidelines almost to the letter and my template is great. Can you accept the answer please.